# Extracting domain name from strings

Tags: php, string, dns

This is my code:

```
From: =?Shift_JIS?B?Y2VudGVyQHlhbWJnbGUuaW4ubmV0?= < center@yambgle.in.net >

From: =?x-sjis?B?+O6C6IKogvH47iAg?= < autovbxds@netltf.ladankhda.in.net >
```

I have the php code for the same, but I would like to have a preg_match code for the same.

Please help.

Comment: do you want to match `yambgle.in.net` and `netltf.ladankhda.in.net` ?

Comment: no i only want yambgle.in.net and ladankhda.in.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should do it

```
$data = 'From: =?x-sjis?B?+O6C6IKogvH47iAg?= < center@yambgle.in.net >';
if(preg_match('/@([^ ]*) /',$data,$result)){
    $domain = $result[1];
    echo $domain;
}
```

Result: yambgle.in.net

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. however it returned me an error. you can check the code here https://ideone.com/HPceQF